# Trigger MS Word macro after save event

Tags: vba, ms-word

My MS Word 2007 template has a footer with the filename in it. The user is going to open the template and do a "Save As..." to make their document.

I want the filename shown in the footer to update immediately to the new filename.

Is there an `AfterSaveEvent` or something that I can use as a hook to start my VBA script that does the update?

Or is there a much easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a macro like this  (I believe it works better if included in the Normal.dot)

```
Sub FileSaveAs()
'
' FileSaveAs Macro
' Saves a copy of the document in a separate file
'
Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs).Show

'returns the name including the .doc extension 
 ChosenFileNameAndExtension = ActiveDocument.Name 'Or use .FullName

' Your code here

End Sub
```

It will be triggered whenever the user selects "File Save As"

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My IT chap's doing some testing on it... will mark this as accepted if it works.

Comment: @blokeley Please post a comment with the result. Good luck!

Comment: excellent, it worked first time. I'll post the full solution below for others.

Answer (score 1):

This worked based on @belisarius' answer:

```
Sub UpdateAll()
    Dim oStory As Object
    Dim oToc As Object

    'Exit if no document is open
    If Documents.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each oStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        oStory.Fields.Update 'Update fields in all stories
    Next oStory

    For Each oToc In ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents
        oToc.Update 'Update table of contents
    Next oToc

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub FileSaveAs()
'
' FileSaveAs Macro
' Saves a copy of the document in a separate file
'
Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs).Show

UpdateAll


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

We know that the `Aftersave` event isn't available for Microsoft Word. But Word allows us to use `BeforeSave` event. I have implemented this solution and it works fine.

First we have to implement `Application.onTime` method in Word `BeforeSave` event as follows

```
Private Sub mobjWord_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Word.Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Word.Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "AfterSave"
End Sub
```

This method will call the method called `AfterSave` after 2 seconds.

```
Public Sub AfterSave()
   While Word.ActiveDocument.Application.BackgroundSavingStatus <> 0
      DoEvents
   Wend
'Implement your code here
End Sub
```

In this method the while loop will be circulated until the document save process is completed. So you can implement you code after the while loop.