# MS Word Save History

Tags: vba, ms-word, save, revision-history

I'm trying to create a save log for a word document. I want to track everyone who saves this document. I couldn't find an easy way of using VBA after a save (at least not in word.)
This [topic on after save events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636625/trigger-ms-word-macro-after-save-event) won't work because this form will be distributed (likely via email) to people who make make edits, save them and send the form back.

I've got this in a table at the end of the document.

```
Last saved by: { LASTSAVEDBY \*Upper\* MERGEFORMAT } on { DOCPROPERTY LastSavedTime \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

I want to trigger an event (VBA or not) that will copy and paste that line (except maintain it's values vs. the field codes) before or after the document is saved.

I pulled this off of [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.beforesave.aspx) but I didn't know how to do they copy paste and save the value of the field codes.

```
Private Sub DocumentBeforeSave()
    Dim vstoDoc As Document = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Me.Application.ActiveDocument)
    AddHandler vstoDoc.BeforeSave, AddressOf ThisDocument_BeforeSave
End Sub 

Private Sub ThisDocument_BeforeSave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.SaveEventArgs) 

 'do my stuff - copy field code, paste as values. 

    If System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show( _
        "Do you want to save the document?", "BeforeSave", _
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
        e.Cancel = True 
    End If 
End Sub
```

To throw a monkey wrench - I'm working with people who likely will have macros disabled (which may make this futile).  Anyone have idea's on how to do this outside VBA? If not - I'll use VBA and mark it a trusted document for certain people.

Answer (score 0):

Look at File Versions (Alt + F, R). Also Track Changes (Alt + T, T) and Protect Document (Alt + T, P) work together.

You can record them (Alt + T, M, R). Although if you can't run macros not much point. BUT you can convert Macros to VBScript and control Word externally. VBScript uses a subset of VBA, but not the syntax that Macro Recorder uses.