# Get the saved file name in VBA for Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need your help to unlock me.

I would like to retrieve the name of the file saved by the user with Word in VBA. I'm using the `BeforeSave` method, but I can not seem to catch the name chosen by the user.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: The new name the file will be saved under is not stored anywhere. You could alternatively create your own save dialog and store the name from that sub.

Comment: Related to but not a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10404689/8769365)

Comment: Please show us the code you have. Otherwise, the question does "not show effort" and any code provided will be more "in context", thus more easily understood. You can use the [edit] link below the question to add more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the save as pane not triggering the `SaveAs()` sub, I think the only reliable way to do this is an `OnTime` event triggered by `DocumentBeforeSave`.

Something like:

```
Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If SaveAsUI = True Then
        Word.Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "AfterSave"
    Else
        DoStuff()
    End if
End Sub
```

```
Sub AfterSave()
    CheckSaveOccured()
    DoStuff()
End Sub
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636625/trigger-ms-word-macro-after-save-event) for a more detailed explanation.